Conceptual questions about Newman-Penrose Formalism
I'm taking an advanced undergraduate self-study course on tetrad methods and Newman-Penrose formalism. I'm following Chandrasekhar's masterpiece Mathematical Theory of Black Holes, I'm working through the first chapter and I come across the definitions of the spin coefficients and Weyl and Ricci scalars. I can understand where the independent components come from but I cannot have an intuition about how they are defined.
For example, I see that out of the 24 independent components of the rotation coefficients $\gamma_{abc} = -\gamma_{bac}$ 16 get used up in the definitions of spin coefficients, but I don't see why say $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma_{100}+\gamma_{230}\right)$ is chosen. Why that particular combination, is there a purpose to be served or are they just defined that way?
I have similar confusions about the choice of Weyl scalars and Ricci scalars. Are there better references where these definitions are explicitly derived (I understand it is a little too much to ask for a better reference than Chandrasekhar's book which is considered THE reference for this topic)?

I would argue that THE reference is the original paper of Newman & Penrose on the topic :) The full reference is
Newman, E., & Penrose, R. (1962). An approach to gravitational radiation by a method of spin coefficients. Journal of Mathematical Physics, 3(3), 566-578.
DOI:10.1063/1.1724257
(Do make sure to also check the Errata correcting 7 typos in the paper.)
From this paper you can see that the rotation coefficients follow most naturally when using the 2-spinor (Weyl spinor) base and the spin connection components $\Gamma_{abcd'}$ in terms of which they read

I do not believe there is any particular logic to this, just assigning these by hand. The components often can be assigned a nice geometrical meaning when $l^\mu,n^\mu$ are null congruences, such as the twisting or shearing of the congruence. A lot of these components vanish in algebraically special space-times for special null-tetrads, and this implies nice properties of the corresponding null congruences.
For the Weyl and Ricci scalars this is also best expressed in the spinor base


where the quantity with the larger number of indices corresponds to the 2-spinor base. The left column corresponds to summing the values of the spinor index in various ways, this is essentially motivated by picking the independent components and trying to write fewer index values than in the spinor base.
It turns out that defining all the Weyl and Ricci components like this is particularly useful for identifying various forms of radiation in the space-time, since the 2-spinor components automatically pick components corresponding to various polarizations of massless waves traveling in the $l^\mu,n^\mu$ directions. (More 2-spinor components means higher and higher spin representations of the corresponding massless fields.)
You can verify this by inserting plane wave solutions for gravitational waves into the Weyl scalar, for instance.

Thanks for the explanations and the reference I'll check it out. I think this formalism makes sense only after sitting down and actually writing out the 24 + 36 + 20 equations! Is there any open source computer algebra software implementation where I can see these in action? (I'm new to posting questions in stackexchange, so I don't know if asking it here is correct)

Hi again! I'm working through the original paper as you suggested, I thought I was following the spinor and dyad notations but I got absolutely stumped when I tried to derive eq. 3.13 in the paper. 3.14 looks even more intimidating. The tools at my hand are $\partial_{ab'}\phi=\phi_{;\mu}\sigma^{\mu}{AB'}\zeta^{A}{a}\zeta^{B'}{b'}$ and the definition of $\Gamma{abcd'}$. Is that all I need? If so how do I begin? Please help.
